# Application failed to resume in time

Tags: iphone, ios

I encounter a "failed to resume in time" crash (which I assume to be watchdog related) on a very specific scenario: Only when resuming from background, and only when doing it within a really short amount of time after going to background (a few seconds at most).

This seems to be the relevant crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: E30F2238-5B15-49A1-BCBC-386791AC93FA
CrashReporter Key:   84f4fb61c9e5c597750146695fffdc55f7273fb7
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         XXXXXXX
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/DE774CCE-D452-418D-A862-4562A0E5F1D0/XXXXXXX.app/XXXXXXX
Identifier:      XXXXXXX
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-01-14 13:15:41.955 +0200
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
XXXXXXX failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 9.140 (user 9.140, system 0.000), 91% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 7.806, 78% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x336fa7cc fsync + 8
1   Foundation                      0x3a444974 _NSWriteBytesToFileWithExtendedAttributes + 668
2   Foundation                      0x3a4446ce _NSWriteBytesToFile + 22
3   Foundation                      0x3a4446ac -[NSData(NSData) writeToFile:atomically:] + 80
4   XXXXXX                          0x001777ee 0xe3000 + 608238
5   CoreFoundation                  0x38361034 _CFXNotificationPost + 1424
6   Foundation                      0x3a437d8c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
7   Foundation                      0x3a43b84e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 26
8   XXXXXX                          0x000e6616 0xe3000 + 13846
9   UIKit                           0x37e050e4 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 780
10  UIKit                           0x37d7b1ea -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2454
11  UIKit                           0x37d7a6d0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
12  UIKit                           0x37d7a11e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
13  GraphicsServices                0x3600d5a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
14  GraphicsServices                0x3600d1ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
15  CoreFoundation                  0x383e5170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
16  CoreFoundation                  0x383e5112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
17  CoreFoundation                  0x383e3f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
18  CoreFoundation                  0x38356eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
19  CoreFoundation                  0x38356d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
20  GraphicsServices                0x3600c2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
21  UIKit                           0x37dce2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
22  XXXXXXX                         0x000e5cd0 0xe3000 + 11472
23  XXXXXXX                         0x000e5c6c 0xe3000 + 11372
```

I've tried debugging this, but it doesn't seem to happen when connected to a debugger (and all relevant info I've found on the matter suggest wacthdog is disabled when connected to debugger), so I then tried logging the process to try and follow what goes on.

I've added logging to all the `AppDelegate` relevant methods (`applicationWillResignActive`, `applicationDidEnterBackground`, `applicationWillEnterForeground`, `applicationDidBecomeActive` and even `applicationWillTerminate`) but got no logs when returning from the background, only when going to background. I understand that some processes can be dispatched in a way that enables them to resume even when the app is in the background for a specified amount of time, but I do not execute any such processes on my own. Perhaps the Facebook SDK does something like that, but I could not find any reference to that either, and the crash logs provide no indication.

I'm a little at a loss here, and would appreciate any push or even nudge in the right direction.

Comment: you probably block the main thread too long, and the iOS terminates the application. you have to push the long procedures to any background thread, it could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is watchdog related.

Is it possible that your writing process takes too much time on the main thread and is blocking that one? That would explain why no log data is shown when coming back from background and that this only happens when resuming very shortly after going to background.

I would recommend doing the following:

1. Writing your data when going into background not in the main thread,
   but using a background task via:

   `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{...`
2. If the app resumes while that background task is still running, act
   correspondingly, e.g. don't read until it finished writing, or don't
   write again if it is still writing. So you need to be aware of your
   own state

Biggest rule: never block the main thread with anything might take longer than a fraction of a second. Move that all into background threads or in this scenario into a background task.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have indeed put me in the right direction... I Want to run a few more tests before I feel this issue was indeed resolved, so I'm not accepting your answer just yet.

Comment: @Kerni I am facing a similar issue.I have followed point 1 stated in your answer but i didn't understand what do u mean by point 2.   How can i check whether the background task has been completed or still in process.Can you please help me with more info.Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply create an boolean iVar which where you store when the background task started and when it ended. So you won't start it again if the ivar says it is still running.

Answer (score 0):

find in which thread you app is crashing put that thread in
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // run that crashing thread here. }); });`